# Load fresh swf from server

Tags: flash, caching

I have a main flash from wich i load another swf file from the server. From time to time i change the second swf file and want to load a fresh copy from the server. I clean the cache from the browser but my client does not know how to do that and it's a pain to give him directions. If i want to load a fresh copy of the main swf i just add a  "main.swf?**version2**" but i can't do that with the loadMovie function in flash.

Any ideas how i can get a fresh copy from the server without changing the name of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i always use a random number

main.swf?version=Math.random()

Comment: yes, that works when you "call" the flash from html, but it won't work if you load a movie clip from another swf with the loadMovie function.

Comment: Why doesn't it work?  I'm fairly certain I've loaded movies programatically that had query parameters.

Comment: my bad...i tested the loadMovie localy on windows...and the url to the file was rong, online works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" value="Thu, 16 Mar 2000 11:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

In the html page that embeds the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve the second .swf with headers that prohibit caching. There are quite a number of ways to do it, depending on your web server.